# $users_ID always gets "2" as value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, logic

I need to get the `users_ID` from `users` table in WordPress if `user-meta-password` is equal to a value I'm comparing through a `foreach` cycle. This is what I've done so far:

```
$wp_users = get_users();
foreach ($wp_users as $usr) {
    $user_meta = get_user_meta($usr->data->ID);
    foreach ($user_meta as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === "user-meta-passport") {
            $passport[] = str_replace(' ', '', $value[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above I get all the users and loop over on the results looking for the right meta value and filling a new array `passport`. The result of `var_dump($passport)` is:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'PP36199230' (length=10)
  1 => string 'PP10731115' (length=10)
  2 => string 'PP73465172' (length=10)
```

Now in other `foreach` statement I try to find the current value (the one I'm looking for) in the `passport` array as so:

```
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    echo str_replace(' ', '', $row[3]) . '<br>';

    if (in_array(str_replace(' ', '', $row[3]), $passport)) {
        $users_ID = $usr->data->ID;
    }
    else {
        $users_ID = "";
    }

    //echo $users_ID . '<br>';
}
```

This is the output of the `echo` inside the `$csv` foreach:

```
PP36199230
PP98933287
PP54832201
PP92098144
PP10731115
PP17566259
PP47997057
PP29364086
PP73465172
```

In my logic if the value is in the first array `$passport`, I should get that current user ID for that `$users_ID = $usr->data->ID;` but surprisingly if I print `echo $users_ID` I get this output:

```
2
2
2
```

When should be something like:

```
3 - the users_ID for value PP36199230
1 - the users_ID for value PP10731115
2 - the users_ID for value PP73465172
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your second foreach inside the first?  If not, then `$usr` isn't changing and `$usr->data->ID` won't change either.

Comment: And how should I do that? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get the $usr from anywhere in the second loop:

```
foreach ($wp_users as $usr) {
    //Snip
}
//$usr is now the last user in $wp_users

foreach ($csv as $row) {
    //Snip
        $users_ID = $usr->data->ID;//Will always be the last user
    //Snip
}
```

As an alternative you could build up the $passport array to map the user-meta-passport to a user id then, in the second loop, you can easily grab the user id using the user-meta-passport value.

Comment: Nevermind I get it or not, maybe by doing this `$passport[$usr->data->ID] = str_replace(' ', '', $value[0]);` will solve the issue, then I got the key with `array_search` is that right?

Comment: @ReynierPM I mentioned in my edit - build $passport by mapping the passport to a userId. I.e. `$passport[str_replace(' ', '', $value[0])] = $usr->data->ID;` then grab the id in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

The $usr variable is only defined inside that foreach loop - try adding it to a higher-scoped array, or adding it to the CSV file.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers.

Comment: I can't do this since the main idea is to match the data coming from a imported file with the existent WP users and by matching passport is the only way

Comment: @JayBlanchard My apologies, did not see this in the comments.  Or is this 'answer' viewed as a comment?

Comment: This answer seems more like a comment since you have not shown the OP to do what you propose.